# Get-AzureVM does not show virtual machine

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I'm using the Azure Free Trial and following the Cloud Ranger training videos.  I have loaded the SDK to Powershell and I can `add-azureaccount` and `get-azuresubscription` with no problem.  I only have one subscription so I'm definitely in the right one.

The display after `Get-AzureSubscription` does not list any supported modes and I can't see any of my services listed -- When I use `Get-AzureVM` nothing displays.  I have a vm, cloud service and a storage account set up in the Azure portal. I can see them in the portal, but can't see them in PS.

Comment: Have you created the VM using "Resource Manager" (in the portal you get 2 options - Resource Manager & Classic)? If that's the case, then please try `Get-AzureRMVM` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603718.aspx).

Comment: 99.99% of everything you want to do with Azure is probably best done using either 1) the Azure portal, and/or 2) Visual Studio.  Q: Does everything look OK in the portal?

Comment: @paulsm4 It's great that you choose to use the portal or visual studio. However: The portal isn't going to help at all with automation/DevOps, and Visual Studio isn't going to help for Mac/Linux users. Further: That discussion is completely orthogonal to the question.

Comment: @ruth1613: Q did you get it working?

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured it out.  I wanted to post in case someone in the future runs into this problem.  I thought the problem might be eliminated when I went from the Azure Free Trial to Pay as You Go.  But it surfaced again.  I created vms in the portal (both in Preview and Manage) but they wouldn't show up in Powershell with Get-AzureVM no matter what I tried.  Finally I gave up and created one in Powershell and then Get-AzureVM returned all the VMs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example session:

1. [Download and Install Azure PowerShell](http://aka.ms/webpi-azps)
2. Start Powershell: `powershell`
3. Log on to Azure: `Add-AzureAccount`
   <= This displays an authentication pop-up for login
4. Check subscription(s): `Get-AzureSubscription`
   <= Everything looks fine...
5. Check RM VMs: `Get-AzureRMContext`
   <= This fails:

`Get-AzureRMContext : Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login.
    At line:1 char:1
    + Get-AzureRMContext
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-AzureRmContext], PSInvalidOperationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.GetAzureRMContextCommand`

6. Run separate `login-AzureRmAccount` <= Get another login popup
7. Check content `Get-AzureRMContext` <= OK
8. Re-run `Get-AzureRMVM` <= Everything works this time: see expected server and server details
9. I was also able to run `Get-AzureWebsite` (to see my deployed REST services), etc.
10. Use `help Get-Azure` for a complete list of query commands.

NOTE:

Dealing with Powershell syntax can be a PITA.

So it's extremely important to make sure everything looks OK in the portal.  That way, you can focus on troubleshooting a PS syntax error - rather than a real configuration problem.

'Hope that helps!

PS:

Here's a useful "cheat sheet":

https://www.opsgility.com/blog/windows-azure-powershell-reference-guide/getting-started-with-windows-azure-powershell/

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  I was never able to see the vm's in powershell that I created using the portal.  However I am able to see the ones I create in powershell in both the portal and thru powershell.  Since I plan on creating most things in powershell this won't be an insurmountable problem, but it does make me reluctant to use the portal.